# grub-install but don't use UUID; bios_grub

Tags: boot, grub2, bios

I've installed Ubuntu 18 with MDADM RAID support, with boot disk as (INTELhd0,gpt2-UUID).  I use bios boot on disks with GPT partitions.  The first partition (hd0,gpt1) is of course the 1MB grub-bios, second partition (hd0,gpt2) is a boot partition which has the full version of grub with the array config modules.  Third partition is OS root system files, in RAID1.  All boot partitions are manually cloned via rsync for simplicity.

When one drive fails, I want the system to still boot. I used *grub install* to install grub on the other disks (TOSHhd0,gpt2-UUID), which unfortunately uses the config from the current boot disk and points the *grub_bios* to the original (INTELhd0,gpt2-UUID) boot disk. If the main INTEL-UUID boot drive fails and it boots from an alternate disk (TOSH-UUID), grub_bios complaints that the (INTELhd0,gpt2-UUID) of the original boot disk containing full grub2 is missing and drops to rescue.  Typing *set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/grub*, then insmod normal, normal boots just fine.

How do I tell grub-install to setup the bios_grub image to look for (hd0,gpt2)/grub instead of INTELhd0,gpt2-UUID/grub?

```
root@testubu:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0     1M  0 part  #this bios_grub points to UUIDsda only
├─sda2    8:2    0   250M  0 part  /boot #also /boot/grub
└─sda3    8:3    0    15G  0 part  
  └─md0   9:0    0    15G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0     1M  0 part  #this bios_grub points to UUIDsdb only
├─sdb2    8:18   0   250M  0 part  #backup /boot directory and /boot/grub
└─sdb3    8:19   0    15G  0 part  
  └─md0   9:0    0    15G  0 raid1 /
```

grub.cfk is setup to use labels for finding the boot partition, so I'm not needing to specify partition numbers.  fstab uses sda2 as its /boot identifier, I should probably change it to LABEL=.

It appears I can manually boot to each disk once, so when I run grub-install /dev/sda it automatically puts its own disk UUID into the grub-bios image.  This just seems like an odd way to do it.